# How to destroy current session id and set new session id using php?

Tags: php, session

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['Ref'])){    
include"secure_db.php";
$LangName=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn_server_link,$_GET['Ref']);
 //Getting name..
 $LangQuery=mysqli_query($conn_server_link, "SELECT * FROM 
 `language_store` WHERE `language_store`.`Lang_Id` = $LangName");
 $FetcHName=mysqli_fetch_array($LangQuery);
 $get_Lang_Id=$FetcHName['Lang_Id'];
 $get_Lang_Name=$FetcHName['Lang_Name'];

session_start();
$_SESSION['lang'] = "$get_Lang_Id";
header('Location: home/');
}
?>
```

I have this code. I received a id using php $_GET method and I started a session using GET value. Now I want to update the session value and destroy the current value. anybody please suggest me what would be the process.

Comment: Is it some of the contents of the $_SESSION array that you want to replace or the id for the session?

Comment: Yes. I need to replace the current session ID

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function session_regenerate_id() to replace the ID for the session:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Have a read through the manual page, including all of the comments on that page and the warning that it has about the usage of the function